# I'm generating a word document with PHP, how do I make a page break?

Tags: php, html, ms-word, page-break

I'm generating a word document with PHP (HTML with ms-word header), is there a way make a page break ?

Right now I'm witing a lot of `<p>&nbsp;</p>` until the page changes, but that's far from satisfying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not tested to see if it works, but you could try:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always" />
```

Answer (score -2):

A page-break has no meaning in HTML. It's more elegant to mark up the text which should be on the next page with, let's say

### Header

. Then, in MS Word, create a style named "H2", and set it to "Page-break before" (Format/Paragraph/Line and Page Breaks).

Comment: As per the title, I'm generatign the Word document through PHP (which is simply HTML opened by Word). Thus it makes no sense to create a style in word, as the word document doesn't exist beforehand.